# Why it works using Ajax POST but not using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, coldfusion, httpwebrequest

Here's a strange thing: I'm trying to send data to a Coldfusion web service via HttpWebRequest (also tried with HttpClient), and I always get a "login page" as response.

BUT, if I do the same thing as Ajax Post, it works.

BUT², if I put the content-type as "application/json" in the Ajax call, it returns the login page as well.

The web service manager says that the service doesn't need login, since we're using VPN to call it. But if I try to access the webservice URI via browser, it opens the login page.

The code in C#:
**[EDIT] Created the object using JsonConvert**

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://url.cfc");

var obj= new 
                                    {
                                        method = "MethodName",
                                        data1 = "123456",
                                        data2 = "aaa"
                                    };

string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

request.Method = "POST";
//request.ContentType = "application/json"; (not using!!!)

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request .GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(postData );
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

And the code in JS:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "http://url.cfc",
      data: ({
          method: "MethodName",
        data1: 123456,
        data2: "aaa" }),
       dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) { 
  console.log(result); },
      error: function (result) { 
  console.log(result); },
   });
});
```

Is there some substantial difference between Ajax call and HttpWebRequest call that can "block" the request using C#? Or maybe I'm failing in put some important data in HttpWebRequest's Header? Moreover: some issue in Coldfusion's web service authorization configuration?

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the _actual_ request that is sent by each call, you will likely find some header values are missing/incorrect

Comment: Your C# `postData` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange where? Is not https://jsonlint.com/ tells me. Even though, it's just an example, my string is being created by JsonConvert and it's ok.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange updated the code to the correct way.

Comment: The AJAX call might add cookies...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to move the methodname to the url instead of passing as a post param.

In Javascript in your AJAX call:

```
url: "http://url.cfc?method=MethodName"
```

and in C#:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://url.cfc?method=MethodName");
```